# Login system using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

first of all i have done it using classes but actually i have to do it using curl. I want to send my email username and password to system and then taking this values for login check and redirect to table.php

This is my service i tried:

```
        case 'LOGIN':
        $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
        $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

        $staffuname         =$comingdata[0];
        $staffpassword      =$comingdata[1];

        try
            {
                $login = $myPDO->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_name='{$uname}' OR user_email='{$uname}') AND user_pass='{$upass}' ")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($login->rowCount() > 0 )
                {
                    Redirect('table.php');
                }else{
                    $data=array("Response"=>"Failed");
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        break;
```

and here is the curl login post:

```
     if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
     {

$uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
$upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

 $query=$uname.'|'.$upass;
 echo $query;
 $params=array(
        'action' => "LOGIN",
        'query' => $query
            );
        $postData='';
        foreach($params as $k => $v){
            $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&';
        }
        rtrim($postData, '&');
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/skynebtrack/pages/dutyservice.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($response);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $cvp=json_decode($response,true);

if($cvp["Response"]=="SUCCESSFULL")
{
    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
    redirect('table.php');
}
else
{

}   
  }
```

i am getting ıname and password but it doesntredirect me to home page. Thanks for yor feedback.

Comment: If that is the same portal. .. Why you need CURL? Make just simple PHP login form

Comment: Because all system goes on webservices. So i have to do it using cURL.

Comment: Oh! Then maybe instead of `redirect()` use `header()` `header("Location: table.php");
die();`

Comment: Tried but not sir. :(

Comment: Are you able to get inide `if($cvp["Response"]=="SUCCESSFULL")` ?

Comment: Unfortunately...

Comment: if your if statement works as need but still have  no redirect you can also try with `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=table.php" />';`

Comment: Can you post response?

Comment: Thank i tried but again same thing. I can see username and password on screen but doesn't redirect...

Comment: Do `var_dump($cvp)` and see what it gives

Comment: It says NULL...but if it is null.. How can i see uname and password.

Comment: There you go! `        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($response);` you do that before `$cvp` you print it out

Comment: I did it already. But it is same... :/

Comment: Does `print_r($response);` returns only username and password? If there are no `Response` in response how you want that to work? Also  `$cvp=json_decode($response,true);` seems to be useless here same as `$cvp["Response"]=="SUCCESSFULL"`

Comment: I did all system like that. Other systems are works perfectly. Bu i dont know what is error at here

Comment: Check if you pass back all needed from webservices.

Comment: Checked. Anyways.. I have to do more try...

Comment: VTC. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Just from the looks of this code, you also ought to read [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021) and [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/8028957), the obligatory [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174), [How to use password\_hash](//stackoverflow.com/q/30279321) -- Those longwinded comments are a good indicator that your question isn't fit for SO yet, might need more debugging, perhaps rather take it to a bulletin board.

Comment: Thank for your understanding. :)

Comment: Warning: your strip_tags() is NOT protecting you from SQL injection, your login code is wide open to SQL injection attack from hackers. also, you shouldn't have to strip anything from either the username nor password. - read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1067003